# Extract year from timestamp into new column

Tags: sql, timestamp, extract

I am fairly new to SQL and need to extract the year from a column that has a date, formatted like this: 2003-05-07T00:00:00+02:00. I want to create a new column with just the year.

I'm assuming it is an EXTRACT() statement, but I'm stuck after that.

SELECT time_stamp_column FROM table_name EXTRACT YEAR(time_stamp_column) INTO new_column

Any suggestions?

Comment: Whats the datatype of that field? A lot of times, dates are stored as varchar for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to have duplicate data in your database. Just do a query on the year of the time_stamp_column anytime you want to know the year.

```
SELECT YEAR(time_stamp_column) FROM tablename WHERE YEAR(time_stamp_column) = 2013
```

Also you might find this helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I do need to use it with CartoCSS and have the year generated and then put in as a value on a style 
[year=2003] {marker-opacity: .1;} 

I don't think I can do that on the fly, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Oracle? If so, you can use `EXTRACT` like you said, but the syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) AS year_value FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
YEAR_VALUE
----------
      2013
```

Answer (score 0):

If year is always 4 digit, you can use `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(time_stamp_column,1,4))`..
This will work if the values are stored as varchar.

If its a timestamp/date, then use Jade's answer.